Salesforce Flow Add CC Recipient Address List Dynamically
When the new account is created, I want to email the Account owner and add some Recipient Address List to the Salesforce Flow. How can we achieve this scenario?

Do you have checked this?

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000392564&type=1 - https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=platform.flow_ref_elements_actions_sendemail.htm&type=5

You can add their email addresses to a text collection via an Assignment after that use a Send Email action and use this collection in the "Recipient Address Collection" field.

Do it like this one and it will work too. Make a flow as desired and an email template with the associated email alert.
Email Alert:
Make email alert on:
Object: Account,
Recipients: Account Owner
Add the people you want to add in CC inside "Additional Emails" area. And select desired From Email Address.
Reference Screenshot of email alert:

Salesforce Flow:
Use the email alert in flow to pass the record id if your flow is on account object as mentioned.
Reference Screenshot of flow:

The above should send the email to mentioned recipient and additional recipients from the email templates.
Note: For this you need to update email alert each time you need to add remove specific address and i think you can add upto 5 additional emails at time. For more dynamic approach i think you should try what Tushar suggessted in the comments: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000392564&type=1

I have created a custom object named CC email__c list in which I have added 4 emails, and I want to add those emails dynamically in the Email action cc recipients list. How can I do that?

You have stored 4 emails in a custom object? Assuming they are stored in fields you might need to use get records element to get the values and then use the "Send Email" action to add values of get records.required field into the "CC Recipient Address List" and trigger the flow it should work. Refer this article: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=platform.flow_ref_elements_actions_sendemail.htm&type=5

Let me explain the whole scenario; I have created a custom object named CC Email List in which I added 4 records for 4 different emails. Then I created a flow so that whenever new account get created a email should sent to account owner as well as the emails which I added in custom object. Now in Email Action eemenet in flow there we have the CC recipient address there I want to add these EMails dynamically. The emails are getting added, but when I debug the flow, one or more email addresses fail, and a validation error occurs even though those are correct emails.
